# Ubuntu 18.04, held broken packages, install opencl

Tags: server, nvidia, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I have this problem: I want install these packages: nvidia-390 (driver) nvidia-libopencl1-390 nvidia-opencl-icd-390 on Ubuntu Server 18.04.

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-29-generic
```

I have installed nvidia-390, further when installing nvidia-libopencl1-390 I have the following errors:

```
# apt install nvidia-libopencl1-390
Reading Package Lists ... Done
Building a Dependency Tree
Reading status information ... Done
Some packages can not be installed. Perhaps you are asking for the impossible,
or use an unstable version of the distribution, where you requested
packages are not yet created or have been removed from Incoming.
The following information may help you:

Packages with unsatisfied dependencies:
  nvidia-libopencl1-390: Depends: nvidia-compute-390 but it can not be installed
E: It is impossible to fix errors, you have held broken packages.
```

The same is true with nvidia-opencl-isd-390.

Such errors are observed on the versions 387,390. Deleted all the packages of the nvidia-*, then installed the 384 version, but 387, 390 also gave an error.

Version 384 packages were installed, entered the command `nvidia-xconfig`, reboot. After that the driver is working, but opencl is not detected by the programs. They say that it is not installed by opencl.

How to fix 384 or fix and install version nvidia's 390 packages?

NEW

Thank you, I did so. First I checked what I needed
ubuntu-drivers device

## ubuntu-drivers devices

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:03.0/0000:0b:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C03sv00001462sd00003281bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

396 is recommended, but there is no opencl 396.

Comment: Thank you, I did so. First I checked what I needed
ubuntu-drivers device
# ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:03.0/0000:0b:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C03sv00001462sd00003281bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

396 is recommended, but there is no opencl 396.

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers devices` is a bit complicated for this task because there are so many dependencies. The easier way to do it is the command `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall ` which resolves all the dependencies automatically, but it does not install opencl. As for installing opencl, read my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the nvidia-driver-390 driver version 390.48 in 18.04 which was installed with the following commands:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install  
sudo reboot
```

The `ubuntu-drivers install` option installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies, and the Nvidia driver will also be updated automatically when an update is available. This command will not install nvidia-libopencl1-390 or libnvidia-libopencl1-390 which you don't need. Instead if you need opencl, install it separately with the following command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-opencl-dev
```

Before you run `ubuntu-drivers install` you must first uninstall all the nvidia-* packages that are currently installed as you did before and then reboot with `sudo reboot`. After you run `sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo apt install nvidia-opencl-dev` you must reboot as usual to enable the changes in graphics drivers with `sudo reboot`

Comment: Did, installed the dev version, the software saw opencl, the opencl libraries also give out an error. Thanks for the help ! It's strange for me that the dev version works without a library

Comment: The dev version of opencl installs all the necessary libraries automatically as its dependencies. You seem to be in better shape now than before because if you install others packages you can save the package names of the additional packages you installed in a text file, and then uninstall them if you get any dependencies errors.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing with opencl that gives out the error. Depending on what you are doing with opencl, this issue might require being asked as a separate question in order to prevent your original question from being closed as too broad.

Comment: The first part (`ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`) did not work for me, with the latest nvidia-driver-396 package(s) due to "unmet dependencies".  However, I installed the drivers as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers and then the `apt install nvidia-opencl-dev` worked well.